# how to have nested mat-option in mat-select angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular7

I have mat-select and mat-datepicker. In mat-select there are 3 option.when I click on 3rd(Custom) option it must show datepicker,without closing mat-select panel.To achieve this is there any plugin.

Edit:

```
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(value)]="selectedOption" (selectionChange)="onSelectChange($event.value,$event)" placeholder="Date Range">

          <mat-option [value]="'Last 24 hours'">Last 24 hours               
          </mat-option>
          <mat-option [value]="'Last 7 days'">Last 7 days
          </mat-option>           

          <mat-option [value]="'Custom'">Custom
            <mat-select>
              <mat-option>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1">
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>



        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

on click of Custom its shows date-picker select .but parent mat-select closes on select of custom option

Comment: Explain the expected behaviour and what you have tried to do so!

Comment: Are you sure about your requirement? I mean: the "must show datepicker" is pretty easy, you only need an `*ngIf="selectedOption === 'Custom'"` on the datepicker. But the "without closing the map-select panel" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @A.Chiesa your right .last time date picker shown separate that is when I click on custom option date picker was shown .

Comment: I'm not sure about your last phrase. What I mean is: why something as simple as
```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="selectedOption === 'Custom'">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```
_outside_ of the mat-select is not ok? The `mat-select` has an expected behaviour, meant for just selecting items on click. You cannot put inside it other controls without some effort.

Comment: @A.Chiesa I want to show datepicker as a mat-option inside mat-select.

Comment: I understand what you want. What I mean is: you shouldn't! ;) You're in for a lot of problems. And probably the easiest option is reimplement a custom select control. Not that I am advising in pursuing that option.

Comment: @A.Chiesa How to implement custom select control

Answer (score 0):

you should use `menu` instead of `select`.

see [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wonvyt).